# Equivalent equations

Tags: differential-geometry

I am looking at the following exercise:

Verify directly that the differential equations in Proposition 9.2.3 are equivalent to the geodesic equations in Theorem 9.2.1.

[image]

[image]

We have that $$\Gamma_{11}^1=\frac{GE_u-2FF_u+FE_v}{2(EG-F^2)}, \ \ \ \ \Gamma_{11}^2=\frac{2EF_u-EE_v-FE_u}{2(EG-F^2)} , \ \ \ \  \Gamma_{12}^1=\frac{GE_v-FG_u}{2(EG-F^2)}, \ \ \ \  \Gamma_{12}^2=\frac{EG_u-FE_v}{2(EG-F^2)}, \\  \Gamma_{22}^1=\frac{2GF_v-GG_u-FG_u}{2(EG-F^2)}, \ \ \ \  \Gamma_{22}^2=\frac{EG_u-2FF_v+FG_u}{2(EG-F^2)}$$

Then we get that the equations of the Proposition 9.2.3 are equal to $$\ddot u+\frac{GE_u-2FF_u+FE_v}{2(EG-F^2)}\dot u^2+2\frac{GE_v-FG_u}{2(EG-F^2)}\dot u\dot v+\frac{2GF_v-GG_u-FG_u}{2(EG-F^2)}\dot v^2=0 \\ \Rightarrow (EG-F^2)\ddot u+\frac{GE_u-2FF_u+FE_v}{2}\dot u^2+(GE_v-FG_u)\dot u\dot v+\frac{2GF_v-GG_u-FG_u}{2}\dot v^2=0$$ 
and 
$$\ddot v+\frac{2EF_u-EE_v-FE_u}{2(EG-F^2)}\dot u^2+2\frac{EG_u-FE_v}{2(EG-F^2)}\dot u\dot v+\frac{EG_u-2FF_v+FG_u}{2(EG-F^2)}\dot v^2=0 \\ \Rightarrow (EG-F^2)\ddot v+\frac{2EF_u-EE_v-FE_u}{2}\dot u^2+(EG_u-FE_v)\dot u\dot v+\frac{EG_u-2FF_v+FG_u}{2}\dot v^2=0$$

The equations of the Theorem 9.2.1 are equal to $$(E_u\dot u+E_v\dot v)\dot u+E\ddot u+(F_u\dot u+F_v\dot v)\dot v+F\ddot v=\frac{1}{2}(E_u\dot u^2+2F_u\dot u\dot v+G_u\dot v^2) \\ \Rightarrow E\ddot u+\frac{E_u}{2}\dot u^2+E_v\dot u\dot v+\frac{2F_v-G_u}{2}\dot v^2+F\ddot v=0$$ and $$(F_u\dot u+F_v\dot v)\dot u+F\ddot u+(G_u\dot u+G_v\dot v)\dot v+G\ddot v=\frac{1}{2}(E_v\dot u^2+2F_v\dot u\dot v+G_v\dot v^2) \\ \Rightarrow F\ddot u+\frac{2F_u-E_v}{2}\dot u^2+G_u\dot u\dot v+\frac{G_v}{2}\dot v^2+G\ddot v=0$$

Is everything correct so far?

How could we continue to show that these equations are equivalent?